# What is `10.0.0.1/32` in networking?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, ip, subnet, cidr

What is the difference between `10.0.0.1/32` and `0.0.0.0/0` in networking?

I am trying to fix this security issue by allowing all traffic through port 22 with cidr_block set to (`0.0.0.0/0)`. After research, `10.0.0.1/32` appears to fix this. However, what is the difference in this context?

Here is the issue https://docs.bridgecrew.io/docs/networking_1-port-security.

Comment: Do you need to allow traffic in from a VPC or from the internet?

Answer (score 4):

That is a [CIDR block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing), which denotes a range of IP addresses. The CIDR block `0.0.0.0/0` denotes every IP address that exists, while the CIDR block `10.0.0.1/32` denotes the range `10.0.0.1` to `10.0.0.1` (in other words, the single IP address `10.0.0.1`).

You can calculate the CIDR range using a utility like [this one](https://www.subnet-calculator.com/cidr.php).